# why am i getting a static injector error?

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi am trying to create a login for a simple angular application! but for whatever reason I keep getting the following error.

> ERROR Error: "StaticInjectorError[LoginModalComponent -> AuthenticationService]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpClient]: 
>       StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]: 
>         NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!"

The process is as such, on the homepage I have a login button which is a modal, I click the modal and this error pops up! I am a begginner and have no clue where to start solving the issue

here is my app.module.ts

```
   import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material';
   import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome';
   import { NgbModule, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
   import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

   import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
   import { HomepageComponent } from './homepage/homepage.component';
   import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser  /animations';
   import { OpenStreetMapComponent } from './open-street-map/open-street-map.component';
   import { AppRoutingModule } from './/app-routing.module';
   import { LoginModalComponent } from './homepage/login-modal/login-modal.component';
   import { AddArtModalComponent } from './open-street-map/add-art/add-art-modal/add-art-modal.component';
   import { AddArtButtonComponent } from './open-street-map/add-art/add-art-button/add-art-button.component';
   import { RecommendButtonComponent } from './open-street-map/recommend-art/recommend-button/recommend-button.component';
   import { RecommendModalComponent } from './open-street-map/recommend-art/recommend-modal/recommend-modal.component';
   import { PopupsComponent } from './open-street-map/popups/popups.component';
   import { fakeBackendProvider } from './_helpers';

   @NgModule({
     declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       HomepageComponent,
       OpenStreetMapComponent,
       AddArtModalComponent,
       LoginModalComponent,
       AddArtButtonComponent,
       RecommendButtonComponent,
       RecommendModalComponent,
       PopupsComponent,
     ],
     imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       BrowserAnimationsModule,
       MatButtonModule,
       MatCheckboxModule,
       AngularFontAwesomeModule,
       AppRoutingModule,
       FormsModule,
       ReactiveFormsModule,
       NgbModule.forRoot()
      ],
      providers: [
        NgbActiveModal
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
      entryComponents: [
        RecommendModalComponent,
        AddArtModalComponent,
        LoginModalComponent
    ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

my login-modal.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../../_services/authentication.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login-modal',
  templateUrl: './login-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login-modal.component.css']
})
export class LoginModalComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;
  error = '';


  constructor(
   public activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService

  ) {
    //redirect to home if already logged in
    if (this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
       username: ['', Validators.required],
       password: ['', Validators.required]
      });

      // get return url from route parameters or default to '/'
      this.returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    }

    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() { return this.loginForm.controls; }

    onSubmit() {
      this.submitted = true;

      // stop here if form is invalid
      if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
        return;
      }

      this.loading = true;
      this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      },
      error => {
        this.error = error;
        this.loading = false;
      });
}
```

}

and my login.html

```
<div class="modal-content" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Admin Login" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header text-center">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Admin Login</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container">
      <form formGroup="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="emailInput">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" formControlName="username" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
          <div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="passwordInput">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" formControlName="password" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
          <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
        </div>
        <button routerLink="/map" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary signInButton modalButtons" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Signed in')">Sign In</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here the authentication.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { User } from '../_models';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    public currentUser: Observable<User>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')));
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public get currentUserValue(): User {
        return this.currentUserSubject.value;
    }

    login(username: string, password: string) {
        return this.http.post<any>(`${config.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
            .pipe(map(user => {
                // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
                if (user && user.token) {
                    // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
                }

                return user;
            }));
    }

    logout() {
        // remove user from local storage to log user out
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
        this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `import { HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";` in your `app.module.ts`. Perhaps try importing the `HttpClientModule`.

Comment: @Narm not too sure! After importing this, i get a completely different error, a syntax error, which doesn't quite make sense. 

 SyntaxError: "StaticInjectorError[LoginModalComponent -> AuthenticationService]: 
  JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Comment: I don't see you importing your `AuthenticationService` in your `app.module.ts` either. That needs to be imported and added to your `providers[]` array.

Comment: @Narm still get that same error

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to include AuthenticationService inside providers array in app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    AuthenticationService
  ],
```

Comment: i added it but I am still getting that same error!

 SyntaxError: "StaticInjectorError[LoginModalComponent -> AuthenticationService]: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Answer (score 0):

What version of angular you are using ?

for version less than 6, you will need to import and provide the required services in your `app.module.ts` in the providers and then remove `{ providedIn: 'root' }` from the service.

If you use angular 6 or 7, ... and you use `{ providedIn: 'root' }` in your service metadata, then you don't need to provide the service in the provider section of `app.module.ts`, only you will need to inject the service in the components where you use it.

Comment: I am using angular 6! I am doing it exactly as you are saying but the error still persists!